# What are usedExports and sideEffects?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, webpack-2, webpack-5

What exactly is the difference between `usedExports` in `optimization` of webpack config and `sideEffects` in `package.json`?

Answer (score 3):

These are two different things.

##### About the `usedExports`:

Consider this as an instruction to Webpack to allow it to do two things:

- Allow the exported identifiers to be renamed to shorter version (name mangling), *By default, during the bundling process, the exported modifiers are not renamed.*
- Allow unused exports to be not exported from a module. *By default, all the exported identifiers (variables, functions, classes, etc.) are exported even if those are not used anywhere in code.*

For example, in the code

```js
// MODULE A
export const myVariable = 10;

export const myFunction1 = () => a1;

export const myFunction2 = () => a2();


// MODULE B
import { myVariable } from './a.js';

// MODULE C
import { myFunction1 } from './a.js';
```

With this flag enabled, in above code, since `myFunction2` is not used anywhere in the code, it would not be exported when the `a.js` module is being exported. Next thing it would probably try is to rename `myVariable` to single letter identifier like `a` and `myFunction1` to `b` or similar. This applies to not just the modules you have authored but also the modules from `node_modules` as well.

##### About the `sideEffects`:

Although module bundler like webpack is smart enough to figure out if there are side effect in a given module, providing explicit `sideEffects` hints adds more confidence for bundler.

When doing the production bundling, the `sideEffects` and `usedExports` is used only if `optimization.providedExports` flag is enabled.

Comment: So in the above example code, `sideEffects` alone would do nothing if `usedExports` is `false`? Nothing as in it would not prune the `myFunction2 ` function code.

Comment: Yes. That's correct, although I don't remember the **default** values that Webpack uses for these flags when bundling for `production` mode. But it would best possible/sensible values.

Comment: Unfortunately, the production build is the same for both `true` and `false` values of `usedExports`. In the development build, I noticed the comment `/* unused harmony export square */`

Comment: `// math.js

export const square = (x) => x * x;
export const cube = (x) => x * x * x;

// index.js
import { cube } from './math';
cube(10)

// webpack.config.js
const path = require('path');
module.exports = {
  mode: "development", entry: { main: "./src/index.js" }, output: {filename: "[name].js", path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist')}, optimization: { runtimeChunk: "single", usedExports: true }};
`